# MSG 2714 There is an object already named

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm using sql server 2008 management studio. Im trying to create two seemingly simple tables but continue getting this error at execution. I have tried changing the names of these tables to many different variations. Nothing is helping. Here below is what I am typing.

```
USE POS410;
go

CREATE TABLE [empl]
(
employeeID INT NOT NULL,
lname VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
fname VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
address VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
city VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
state VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
areacode INT NOT NULL,
tnumber INT NOT NULL,
EEO1classification VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
hiredate DATE NOT NULL,
salary INT NOT NULL,
gender VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
age INT NOT NULL,
clocknumb INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(employeeID),
UNIQUE(employeeID),
UNIQUE(clocknumb),
FOREIGN KEY(clocknumb) REFERENCES [jb_ttl](Empnum),
);
go

CREATE TABLE [jb_ttl]
(
EEO1 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
JobTitle VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
JobDscrpt TEXT NOT NULL,
ExemptNonExemptStatus VARCHAR NOT NULL,
Empnum INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Empnum),
);
go
```

Here is the error report:

Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 2 There is already an object named 'empl' in the database. Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 2 There is already an object named 'jb_ttl' in the database.

Comment: What happens when you narrow down the problem a bit? Maybe only create one table? Maybe leave some columns out?

Comment: Sorry, where is the error report?

Comment: A full error message would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that you've tried to run this script more than once. It would have failed the first time because you're trying to create the first table with a foreign key to the second, which didn't exist yet. I use the word "didn't" because if my guess is correct, it does now, and that's why you're getting the object already exists error.

As a side note, SQL has supported wrapping DDL (creating/modifying objects) at least going back to 2005. I normally wrap table changes in transactions, and don't commit the transaction until everything goes through with no error messages.

Comment: You are correct. I tried creating the two tables at the same time with the fk relation all in one blow. Is this the problem?

Comment: It would have worked if you had the create statement for jb_ttl first.

Comment: I dropped the job title table and changed the employee table to jobholder and used jbhlder for short. It was successful.

Comment: Thanks Larry. Now that I think about it that makes a whole lot of sense. Now I will make the job title table and come back and alter it later.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a run to confirm if jb_ttl already exists:

```
 select * from master.dbo.sysobjects where [name] = 'jb_ttl'
```

That will show you if anb object named jb_ttl already exists.  Could it already exist as a procedure or trigger perhaps?

Comment: I went ahead and changed the names. Is there a way to open up the tables that were created in this manner(T-sql)?